# Comparing $\left({\frac{2^{10}}{11}}\right)^{11}$ and $\binom{10}1^2\cdot\binom{10}2^2\cdot\binom{10}3^2\cdot\binom{10}4^2\cdot\binom{10}5$

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality, combinatorial-proofs

is

A. Strictly larger than $\binom{10}{1}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{2}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{3}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{4}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{5}$

B. Strictly larger than $\binom{10}{1}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{2}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{3}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{4}^2$ but strictly smaller than  $\binom{10}{1}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{2}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{3}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{4}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{5}$

C. less than or equal to $\binom{10}{1}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{2}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{3}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{4}^2$

D. Equal to $\binom{10}{1}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{2}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{3}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{4}^2 \cdot \binom{10}{5}$

Here is the answer I already wrote that very day here:

Indeed using AM-GM inequality :

$(\frac{2^{10}}{11})^{11} = (\frac{1+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{10}{6}+\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{8}+\binom{10}{9}+\binom{10}{10}}{11})^{11}$

=$(\frac{2+2 \cdot (\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4})+\binom{10}{5}}{11})^{11}$

Now we know that $(\frac{2+2 \cdot (\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4})+\binom{10}{5}}{11}) > [\binom{10}{1}^{2}\cdot \binom{10}{2}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{3}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{4}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{5} ]^{\frac{1}{11}}$.... [By AM-GM Inequality]

Also $(\frac{2+2 \cdot (\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4})+\binom{10}{5}}{11})^{11}= (\frac{2^{10}}{11})^{11}$

$\implies  (\frac{2^{10}}{11})^{11} >  \binom{10}{1}^{2}\cdot \binom{10}{2}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{3}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{4}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{5}$

Hence option A (proved)

I did this all by myself. No plagiarism. No help sought.No books used and no internet reference used. Last time I answered I was alleged to have plagiarized here on this platform.

Comment: Did you immediately eliminate any of those options? Did you calculate what $\dfrac{2^{10}}{11}$ is, roughly?

Comment: @ Joffan Please see my own answer. I tried to solve it. And your answer is 93.something $\approx$ = 93

Comment: @stevengregory No `\dfrac` in titles please (unless this is absolutely necessary, which is not so in the present case).

Comment: @did - sorry, now I know

Comment: Users kindly note I attempted to reopen the question as it may help others which is I think the morale of this platform. Now do not pour your personal anguish by downvoting or closing the question. You know quite well the question and its efforts both have merit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed using AM-GM inequality :

$(\frac{2^{10}}{11})^{11} = (\frac{1+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{10}{6}+\binom{10}{7}+\binom{10}{8}+\binom{10}{9}+\binom{10}{10}}{11})^{11}$

=$(\frac{2+2 \cdot (\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4})+\binom{10}{5}}{11})^{11}$

Now we know that $(\frac{2+2 \cdot (\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4})+\binom{10}{5}}{11}) > [\binom{10}{1}^{2}\cdot \binom{10}{2}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{3}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{4}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{5} ]^{\frac{1}{11}}$.... [By AM-GM Inequality]

Also $(\frac{2+2 \cdot (\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{3}+\binom{10}{4})+\binom{10}{5}}{11})^{11}= (\frac{2^{10}}{11})^{11}$

$\implies  (\frac{2^{10}}{11})^{11} >  \binom{10}{1}^{2}\cdot \binom{10}{2}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{3}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{4}^{2} \cdot \binom{10}{5}$

Hence option A (proved)

I did this all by myself. No plagiarism. No help sought.No books used and no internet reference used. Last time I answered I was alleged to have plagiarized here on this platform.

Comment: Note that $\binom{10}{1}^2=\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{10}{9}$, and the same for all the others. Multiplying by $\binom{10}{0}\cdot\binom{10}{10}$, we see that the expression from option A is equal to the product of all the binomial coefficients $\binom{10}{n}$. This ought to make AM-GM more immediately applicable.

Comment: Using that the RHS is $$\prod_{k=0}^{10}{10\choose k}$$ without identifying  each ${10\choose k}$ with ${10\choose10-k}$ would yield a more readable proof.

Comment: But @Did  is my proof wrong anyway?

Comment: Did I say that? Please read my previous comment, thanks in advance.